# "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime" and "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

I'm trying to run some instances of some ImageAI code and some separate OpenCV codes. The code that gives out the error uses is the following:

```
    from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
detector.setModelPath(os.path.join(execution_path, "yolo.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path, "image2.jpg"),
                                             output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path, "image2new.jpg"),
                                             minimum_percentage_probability=30)

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"], " : ", eachObject["percentage_probability"], " : ", eachObject["box_points"])
print("--------------------------------")
```

and the error it spits out is:

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Okan/Desktop/face-detect/ImageAI-LiveVideoDedection.py", line 1, in <module>
    from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from imageai.Detection.keras_retinanet.models.resnet import resnet50_retinanet
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\keras_retinanet\models\resnet.py", line 19, in <module>
    import keras
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Okan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The weird thing is, on my desktop the code worked perfectly for one or two times. Then, without changing anything, the same error started to show up just like my laptop, which never got to run the code properly. This made no sense to me so I am here asking for help. I would appreciate any kind of support over this. The "solutions" on the internet were mostly uninstalling and reinstalling both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu (In same or older versions with pip), and I don't think it has worked. Again, any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.